# Story about a fortune teller who only makes 2 predictions

Tags: story-identification

About 20 years ago, my cousin was telling me about a story where this amateur fortune-teller only gives two predictions: "You will meet a tall, dark man" and "You will find a fortune in gold" (or something like that). She somehow gets a wish, and wishes to make true predictions.

However, instead of being able to predict what will happen, she keeps giving the same two predictions, and they start coming true. Eventually the city where she's operating becomes entirely populated with tall, dark men (because the ones who meet them get nervous and leave, and the ones who get rich leave to enjoy it.)

Unfortunately, this is all the detail I can remember, and I asked my cousin and he doesn't really remember it either.

Comment: This sounds like fun! Any chance your cousin made this story up his/herself?

Comment: He described it as being something he had read or experienced recently, though I suppose there's no guarantee he was being truthful :P